# Deformed Navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm not sure what happened, but while editing the title of my Navigation bar, the Navigation bar suddenly became deformed like this:

[image: Deformed Navi bar from main.storyboard]

On the device, the navigation bar seems to be twice the regular height:

[image]

The navigation bar is generated by connecting a navigation controller via the storyboard. It was working fine for weeks until now. I tried the following in an attempt to remedy the problem:

1. Clean + Build
2. Restart Xcode
3. Restart my macbook
4. Turning off and on my size classes
5. Deleting the Navigation controller and dragging a new one back on screen.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like the view controller embedded in the navigation controller is whats corrupt.

Did you try re-creating the view controller as well?

Comment: Yea, I did. I ended up restoring to my previous commit to solve the issue. Bummed, still have no idea why.